# Setup email notification with rake task error trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, rake, actionmailer

I have a rake task that uses Feedjira to fetch content from a bunch of RSS feeds that throws an error when a feed changes address.

I'd like to automate an email sent to notify me of the error. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a gem designed to send emails on failed rake tasks, see below link.

https://github.com/nikhaldi/exception_notification-rake